# Retrieve first n levels of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

In python, I have a dictionary of this type:

```
dict= {"a":{'aa': 1},
    "b":{'ba': 2,
         'bb': 3,
         'bc': -1},
    "c":{'ca': 0,
         'cb': 3,
         'cc': 2}}
```

I would like to get this:

```
dict= { "a":{'aa'},"b":{'ba',
         'bb',
         'bc'}, "c":{'ca',
         'cb',
         'cc'}}
```

Which is basically the first two values of the dictionary without the values in the 2nd level.
Is there any way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want to get the keys of each inner dictionary as a set.

This can be done in a dictionary comprehension:

```
original = {"a":{'aa': 1}, "b":{'ba': 2, 'bb': 3, 'bc': -1}, "c":{'ca': 0, 'cb': 3, 'cc': 2}}

result = {k: set(v.keys()) for k, v in original.items()}
print(result)
```

which gives:

```
{'a': {'aa'}, 'b': {'bc', 'bb', 'ba'}, 'c': {'ca', 'cc', 'cb'}}
```

Note: it's best to avoid using `dict` as a variable name since it clashes with the builtin type `dict`.

---

There are also a couple of more concise syntactic options, making use of the fact that iterating over a dictionary iterates over its keys. Both of the following work:

```
result = {k: set(v) for k, v in original.items()}
```

or

```
result = {k: {*v} for k, v in original.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

use a dictionary comprehension

```py
dic1 = {"a":{'aa': 1}, "b":{'ba': 2, 'bb': 3, 'bc': -1}, "c":{'ca': 0, 'cb': 3, 'cc': 2}}

dic2 = { k1: {k2 for k2 in v1}  for k1,v1 in dic1.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip and map to extract the first two levels (but, for this to work, you can't call your variable `dict`):

```
d = {"a":{'aa': 1},
    "b":{'ba': 2,
         'bb': 3,
         'bc': -1},
    "c":{'ca': 0,
         'cb': 3,
         'cc': 2}}

d2 = dict(zip(d,map(set,d.values())))

{'a': {'aa'}, 'b': {'ba', 'bc', 'bb'}, 'c': {'cc', 'cb', 'ca'}}
```

You could also use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d2 = {k:{*v} for k,v in d.items()}
```

If you need to preserve the key order of the 2nd level (which a set will not do), you can place them in lists instead:

```
d2 = dict(zip(d,map(list,d.values())))

d2 = {k:[*v] for k,v in d.items()}

{'a': ['aa'], 'b': ['ba', 'bb', 'bc'], 'c': ['ca', 'cb', 'cc']}
```

or tuples:

```
d2 = dict(zip(d,map(tuple,d.values())))

d2 = {k:(*v,) for k,v in d.items()}

{'a': ('aa',), 'b': ('ba', 'bb', 'bc'), 'c': ('ca', 'cb', 'cc')}
```

If you need to generalize this to any number of levels, you can make a recursive function to drill down the specified number of levels:

```
def topLevels(D,level):
    if not isinstance(D,dict): return D
    if level == 1:             return list(D) 
    return {k:topLevels(v,level-1) for k,v in D.items()}

print(topLevels(d,2))

{'a': ['aa'], 'b': ['ba', 'bb', 'bc'], 'c': ['ca', 'cb', 'cc']}
```